# Does ServiceStack ORMLite support HierarchyId at this point?

Tags: c#, sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, hierarchyid

I am looking at this post which is probably not as updated:

[SQL Server specific types support for OrmLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924173/sql-server-specific-types-support-for-ormlite)

However, I am trying to see if it is supported currently. If not, what is the best way to support these kind of "not so usual" types while using ORMLite OR any ORM in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For any tabular results you can use [Custom SQL API's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-sqlexpressions-with-custom-sql-apis) to map them to POCO's, but any non-standard esoteric Data types are not supported with OrmLite's typed API's.

Feature Requests for OrmLite can be added on [ServiceStack's UserVoice](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests).