# Representing Trees in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I want to create a system of categories and sub categories for my website. Taking the StackOverflow tag system as an example, I want to represent a hierarchy like:

```
ProgrammingConcepts
    Functions
    FlowControl
        Branching
        Looping
    Datastructures
        List
        Tree
```

Users should be able to search this tree, so a user could search for `FlowControl` and get any articles tagged as `FlowControl`, `Branching` or `Looping`.

How should I represent this in my database? The obvious solution is to have a table like this:

```
Categories
    CategoryId int <PK>
    ParentId int <Nullable>
    CategoryName
```

I feel that this might be a hard to query on though. I'm just starting to learn asp.net mvc - in particular, the entity framework system seems to work much better than how I have previously worked with the database. Does this play nice with a tree structure?

Comment: That'll do.  Common Table Expressions let you do recursive queries to walk the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a db design point of view, that kind of design is the most cross-database compatible - just stick a FK constraint on the ParentId column to reference CategoryId.

In SQL Server-only world, as of SQL Server 2008 there is a [hierarchyid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) datatype specifically to facilitate the storage of hierarchical data.

I'm not sure if it's still the case, but I believe hierarchyid is not supported by Entity Framework though so may need a workaround to go down that route.
e.g. [HierarchyID in Entity Framework not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316069/hierarchyid-in-entity-framework-not-working)

Comment: HierarcyID won't be officially supported until EF 5 and .net framework 4.5.  Although, I used heierarcyID in EF 4.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347860/is-there-a-practical-way-to-use-the-hierarchyid-datatype-in-entity-framework-4